# MySQL optimizing simple database

Tags: mysql, database, optimization

A bit of a real rookie question, but I'm really struggling to wrap my head around the logic round this one.

What would be the best way to link `tournament_ID` and `tournament_name` without having to create another table (or should I create another table?)

Notice how there is an AI PRIMARY KEY for `tournament_ID` but does not match the `tournament_name` correctly.

**EXAMPLE**

table tournaments

[image]

Current setup is `tournament_ID` AI PRIMARY KEY. Thus How would I correctly link that to `tournament_name`

Comment: You should create a new table called ``tournaments`` in which store the AI PRIMARY key id and tournament_name and create second table called tournament_teams and add tournament id as foreign key which is referencing to your tournament's table's primary key.

Comment: Is it in anyway possible that I can bypass the creation of a new table

Comment: Yes. You could stop using a relational database management system altogether

Answer (score 0):

You should create a pivot table to store each teams participations and results.

In your current db design there is a possibility of data duplication.

My proposed db design would be

- teams
- tournaments
- team_tournaments (id, team_id,tournament_id, dates, results)

And create a view for fetching a result through joins.

Comment: Dates? What would you put in dates?

Comment: I would advise against the creation of Views in MySQL. They seem like a good idea, but in practice rarely offer any benefit over a regular query.

Comment: By dates i mean any additional data thats important for this relationship

Comment: Well views have its own advantages like it help us simplify the complex queries, access control, computed values.

Comment: Yes we do need to watch if we are changing base tables being used in views.